# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in *ngIf, no Lifecycle hooks used

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm encountering the Following Error:

> Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '[object Object]'. Current value: 'false'.

This is the template of my minimal reproducible example:

```html
  <ng-container *ngFor="let element of elements">

    <text-display-component
      *ngIf="getText(element) as text"
      [text$]="text"
    >
    </text-display-component>

  </ng-container>
```

The corresponding method looks like this:

```js
  getText(element: Element): Observable<string> | false {
    if (element.type !== 'text') {
      return false;
    }
    if (
      this.textBlockSubsriber[this.textBlockSubsriber.length - 1] &&
      !this.textBlockSubsriber[this.textBlockSubsriber.length - 1].closed
    ) {
      this.textBlockSubsriber[this.textBlockSubsriber.length - 1].next(
        element.content
      );
      return false;
    }

    const textBlockObservable = new Subject<string>();
    this.textBlockSubsriber.push(textBlockObservable);

    this.textBlocks.push(textBlockObservable);
    this.textBlockSubsriber[this.textBlockSubsriber.length - 1].next(
      element.content
    );

    return this.textBlocks[this.textBlocks.length - 1];
  }
```

[Full Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sno82u?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

#### This is trying to achieve:

- as soon as an element with the type "text" occurs, it should create a `<text-display-component>`
- this element should then get an observable, where the text to be displayed will be published on
- if another element with the type "text" occurs that is related to the first text block, its content should be published to the observable
- if another element containing text, which is *not* related to any other text blocks, occurs, a new observable and a new display `<text-display-component>` should be created
- Elements with other types should be displayed if they occur (not included in the minimal reproducible example)

Please assume that I have my reasons to use this approach, my actual problem is considerably more complex than this minimal reproducible example.

#### What I have tried

- split the method into one method checking if the component should be displayed and one getter method for the observable

Comment: `getText` shouldn't have side effects if it's being called from the template in an `ngIf` (arguably, you shouldn't be calling a function at all there, but that's not the main issue). That function will be called *repeatedly* as the template re-renders itself on events. If it's returning inconsistent values, change-detection will get messed up. Maybe emit to a behavior subject that holds the current "should  the element be shown" state, and then check the value of the behavior subject in the `ngIf`.